# How to shim a Bootstrap Plugin installed with jspm / system.js needing global jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jspm, es6-module-loader

I have a ES6 Setup working with jspm and system.js with a additonal registered endpoint for bower. I need that endpoint due to the fact that installing Boostrap via npm or github does not provide the necessary less files for Bootstrap (anymore).

However, I want to use some of the Bootstrap Plugins (i.e. collapse). As they are simple jQuery Plugins with no AMD or CommonJS syntax they need jQuery globally.

I have no clue at all how to shim the config.js file of system.js to achieve that. You can pass custom overrides like this

```
{
  "main": "js/jquery.keyboard.js",
  "shim": {
       "js/jquery.keyboard": {
       "deps": ["jquery"]
  }
},
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "*"
    }
}
```

which seems to be the 'official way' to shim a jQuery Plugin.

However, I am installing a whole framework with multiple folders and files not just a single plugin (so, as mentioned above, Bootstrap is installed via a bower endpoint for jspm)

Any suggestions?